# How to find the value of $x$ that satisfies $3x=4$ in $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Let $\mathbb Z_5 = \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$.
The value of $x$ which satisfies the equation $3x = 4\bmod 5$ is...?

The answer is $3$. I understand *why* the answer is $3$, but not *how* it was derived. Is there an equation or process I can use that will give me the correct answer no matter how large the numbers in the equation?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: On this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial. I will edit your question to show what this produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the inverse of $3$ modulo $5$. By Bézout’s identity, there are integers $x$ and $y$ such that $3x+5y=1$, which you can find with the (reverse) Euclidean algorithm:
\begin{align}
\color{red}{5}&=\color{red}{3}\cdot1+\color{red}{2}\\
\color{red}{3}&=\color{red}{2}\cdot1+\color{red}{1}\\
\color{red}{2}&=\color{red}{1}\cdot2+0
\end{align}
The reverse algorithm gives
\begin{align}
\color{red}{1}&=\color{red}{3}+\color{red}{2}\cdot(-1)\\
&=\color{red}{3}+(\color{red}{5}+\color{red}{3}\cdot(-1))\cdot(-1)\\
&=\color{red}{3}\cdot(1+1)+\color{red}{5}\cdot(-1)\\
&=\color{red}{3}\cdot2+\color{red}{5}\cdot(-1)
\end{align}
which shows we can choose $x=2$ and $y=-1$. Since $3\cdot2+5\cdot(-1)=1$, we have
$$
2\cdot3\equiv 1\pmod{5}
$$
and so
$$
2\cdot3x\equiv2\cdot4\pmod{5}
$$
which gives
$$
x\equiv3\pmod{5}
$$
Of course, for congruences modulo $5$ it's much easier to do trial and error, that is, trying $3\cdot m$ for $m=1,2,3,4$ and stop when the hit is found.

On the other hand, the above method will work for *every* problem of the form
$$
ax\equiv b\pmod{n}
$$
where $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

Comment: "2⋅3≡1(mod5) and so 2⋅3x≡2⋅4(mod5)" Could you please explain how you managed to get to  2⋅3x≡2⋅4(mod5) from 2⋅3≡1(mod5)? Where does the 2 and 4 on the RHS come from?

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler Isn't $2\cdot3\equiv 1\pmod{5}$? Then $2\cdot3x\equiv x\pmod{5}$. Thus, multiplying both sides by $2$ you get $x\equiv 8\pmod{5}$; finally $8\equiv3\pmod{5}$.

Comment: I don't understand how you get x≡8(mod5) when multiplying both sides by 2 from 2⋅3x≡x(mod5)? Wouldn't it become 4⋅3x≡2x(mod5)?

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler Start from $3x\equiv 4$ and multiply by $2$ both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Your candidates are $$0,1,2,3,,4 $$

We can check each of them to see which one satisfies the equation $$ 3x=4 \pmod 5$$

For $$x=3$$ we get $$3x =9 \equiv4 \pmod 5 $$ Other candidates do  not satisfy the equation.

Thus the only answer $$ x\equiv 3\pmod 5 $$

Comment: What if $\mathbb Z_n$ = where n = a large number?

Comment: If you have $a \equiv r \mod{b}$ this means that there exists $q$ with $bq + r = a$. So here you can write $5q + 4 = 3x$ and sort of work it out from there (you need to show such a $q$ exists for some $x$, sometimes this is guessable).

Answer (score 0):

Consider equations of the form $m\cdot x = n\bmod p$, where $p$ is a prime number.
The other answer is a correct way to derive the solution, but it takes as many as $p$ tries to find it in the worst case. A more efficient solution is the following. First, compute $m^{-1}$, that is, the only solution $y$ to the equation $m\cdot y = 1\bmod p$. This can be done using the [extended euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). Then, let $x:= m^{-1}\cdot n$. One can then check that $m\cdot x = mm^{-1}n \bmod p = n\bmod p$.

In case $p$ is not a prime number, one can also use this method in the case that $m$ and $p$ are coprime (which guarantees the existence of $m^{-1}$). Suppose now that $p$ and $m$ share a factor, and call it $q$. If $n$ is not divisible by $q$, then there is no solution (you can prove this using arithmetic modulo $q$). If $q$ also divides $n$, then the equation reduces to $\frac{m}{q}\cdot x = \frac{n}{q}\bmod \frac{p}{q}$. You can now continue this process, until you find a solution.